# Acidic strength of organic acids. Substituted PhCOOH acids

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance

Could someone please explain the order of acidity of ortho, para and meta substituted benzoic acids with the substituent as methyl group? 
Methyl group operates +I and +R effect, I believe.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Comment: Related: [Why is o-toluic acid (2-methylbenzoic acid) more acidic than benzoic acid?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/20189/7951)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ortho substituted benzoic acid is most acidic, followed by the meta substituted and finally para substituted benzoic acid.

The methyl group, when at ortho position, causes [steric inhibition of resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steric_effects#Other_steric_effects), which essentially means that the $\ce{-COOH}$ group goes out of the plane of the benzene ring (due to steric hindrance from the $\ce{-CH3}$ group). Due to this, the benzene's $\pi$ electrons can no longer be transferred to the central carbon of the $\ce{-COOH}$ group by resonance, hence increasing the positive charge on it. This makes the hydrogen of the $\ce{-COOH}$ group more acidic.

When the methyl group is on meta position, it operates by +I, thus reducing its acidity. When on para position, it operates by both +I and +R (actually +H, which means [hyperconjugation effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconjugation)), hence decreasing the acidic strength even more.