# Why is p-toluidine more basic than m-toluidine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toluidine

In m-toluidine the $\ce{CH3}$ group is closer to $\ce{N}$ so shouldn't that increase the electron density on $\ce{N}$ and make it a stronger base?

Comment: Related: [Ortho-effect in substituted aromatic acids and bases](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7683/4945)

Answer (score 2):

In p-toluidine you are not actually considering the hyper conjugating structures due to which the compound becomes more basic than m-toluidine which only has it's +I effect and I would like to suggest you that as far as I know resonance effect "usually" overpowers the other effect!