# Is steric inhibition of resonance, or of protonation, dominant in 0-substituted anilines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance

There's a question about inhibition of resonance:

[Is steric inhibition of resonance or steric inhibition of protonation dominant in o-toluidine?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87461/is-steric-inhibition-of-resonance-or-steric-inhibition-of-protonation-dominant-i)

If you look at Martin's answer he says that CH3 is not bulky enough to cause steric inhibition of resonance. What if I considered a group such as ethyl or propyl or even bulkier, then would we observe SIP (steric inhibition of protonation) as well as steric inhibition of resonance?

What would dominate?

Comment: You can make a follow-up question if it's significantly different.