# Steric Inhibition of Resonance in ortho-substituted Benzoic Acids

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds

It is given that due to Steric Inhibition of Resonance (SIR), the acidity of ortho-substituted benzoic acid increases with respect to benzoic acid. However, I'm unable to understand the reason behind this fact.

We know that resonance stabilises a molecule and the absence of which decreases the stability. In case of ortho substituted benzoic acids, resonance is inhibited due to the loss of planarity due to the steric interactions from the ortho substituent.

If this is the case then the conjugate base of the acid will not be stabilized by resonance with the benzene ring. So it seems the ortho-substituted benzoic acid will not readily donate H+ and is less acidic than benzoic acid, contrary to what is being given in various sources.

Then kindly explain why is ortho-substituted benzoic acid is more acidic than benzoic acid.

Comment: which ortho substituent are you refering to?

Comment: Think of a localized, in plane, benzoate conjugate base. The carbonyl can busy itself by resonance with the ring or resonate with the localized charge-bearing oxygen. The carbonyl is splitting its effort. But in the out-of-plane conformation (say, from o-toluic acid) the ring resonance is lost and the carbonyl can now focus on stabilizing the charge on oxygen. On this basis, the out-of-plane acid would be predicted to be more acidic..

Comment: @Waylander  Ortho-substituents like alkyl group(methyl,ethyl,etc.), halogens(F,Cl,Br,I), etc., where the SIR effect depends on the size of the substituent. The substituent I referred does not include small ones like hydroxyl or amine groups.

Comment: @user55119  Ok I understood your point. But we know resonance is a stabilizing phenomenon and more the number of resonance structures, more must be the stability right. This one confuses me. Kindly guide me.

Comment: Ortho effect is discussed in the following link . https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/ortho-effect-in-substituted-aromatic-acids-and-bases&ved=2ahUKEwj1z9205eHjAhUJL48KHVdoDqsQjjgwG3oECAoQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1YoZ5Nl4BKSodJUJesaS4y

Comment: Here resonance is destabilizing as resonance here would mean that two oxygens will have negative charge and that would destabilize the conjugate base.

Comment: @ChakravarthyKalyan: Thanks. It was informative but didn't clarify my doubt.

Comment: *In case of ortho substituted benzoic acids, resonance is inhibited due to the loss of planarity due to the steric interactions from the ortho substituent.* This is incorrect for most substituents in 2 position. SIR is a very fuzzy subject and it is based on false premises. All steric effects are essentially a consequence of electronic effects; it is therefore a balance between electronic effects to begin with. It is unfortunately more complicated than what some books make it out to be.

Answer (score 0):

### Important information before understanding the reason for steric inhibition of resonance and the ortho effect

In general, resonance stabilizes a molecule. But in the case of carboxylic acids, the conjugate base (anion after losing $\ce{H+}$) there are two equivalent resonance structures.
Take the example of acetic acid, $\ce{CH3COOH}$, and thus acetate ion, $\ce{CH3COO-}$:

[image: Resonance Structures of Acetate Ion]

The hybrid would look something like this:

[image: RH of Acetate Ion]

It could be easily seen that equivalent resonance structures mostly stabilise the hybrid greatly.
Therefore, equivalent resonance tends to stabilize a molecule/compound more than normal resonance. (in most cases)

Now let's take the case of *o*-toluic acid.

[image]

There are two ways by which resonance can take place:

[image]

- In (I), it takes place through $\ce{-COOH}$. Its ion is expected to be more stable due to the above result. Also, here $\ce{OH}$ is highly polar and it will tend to lose $\ce{H+}$ to become uncharged and thus be more stable (as compared to $\ce{O-}$).
- In (II), it takes place through the ring. Its ion is less stable due to more formal charge and less aromatic character (due to + on the ring). Also, $\ce{OH}$ is less polar than $\ce{H+}$ due to the above point.

Therefore, it will be better to prevent the taking place of resonance through ring.

That is done by $\ce{-CH3}$ group which provides bulky group repulsion and takes the ring out of the plane of $\ce{-COOH}$ and thus providing condition for equivalent resonance in $\ce{-COOH}$.

Comment: If you want more explanation on Ortho-Effect. Visit here:- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/ortho-effect-in-substituted-aromatic-acids-and-bases?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I've learnt that more the number of resonance structures more stable the compound is. I understood equivalent resonance structures are possible in all circumstances (whether there is SIR or not). But I don't understand why the molecule gets destabilised if we count the resonance between the carboxylic group and the ring. However, I'm glad that you understood my question properly.

Comment: Its not destabilised, its just less stabilised. The compound would prefer to be more stable rather than being less stable.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup, and removed some of the obnoxious markup. You can find more about editing [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945).

Comment: No problem, unfortunately I have to tell you, that what you write is not correct. The 'equivalent resonance' is a widely propagated myth, it doesn't hold up to any scientific rigor. Resonance in itself is only a result from our inability to grasp the actual bonding description.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン But it is usually taught to us in this way, even written in books. Equivalent Resonance Str. tend to stabilize the hybrid. What is the real reason then for Carboxylic Acids to be quite acidic?

Comment: It is very unfortunate that this has not yet been purged from the syllabus and textbooks. It remains a popular concept, even though it is of little to no use. It is a post-hoc rationalisation based on a few cases, which cannot be generalised; it uses reverse argumentation (i.e. it presents the reasons for something as the conclusion of something else).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン If a person has difficulty in understanding a concept, complicating it for them even more is not the step! You needn't bring down every "novice user" by saying "It is very unfortunate that this has not yet been purged from the syllabus and textbooks". Either leave a constructive comment, or give a detailed answer as to WHY it's wrong, it helps imrove morale of such users.

Comment: @BongoMan this is an answer and as an answer it should be correct. It isn't. I don't think the author has had any difficulty understanding what they had written. It also is not their fault to be taught a wrong theory. However, it shouldn't be taught to others as the truth. If they wanted to have a detailed explanation, they could ask a question. The comment section is not the place for an elaborate correction. So in my mind, it was reasonable, constructive criticism and an explanation for my down vote. This is so often demanded here.