# Why is N,N,2,6-tetramethylaniline less basic than N,N,2-trimethylaniline?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines

According to me, *N*,*N*,2,6-tetramethylaniline should be more basic than *N*,*N*,2-trimethylaniline due to more steric inhibition to resonance, but the answer is given opposite. What is the reason for that?

Comment: It increases basicity as well as acidity.That's the reason why 2-methyl-n,n-dimethylaniline is more basic than aniline

Comment: @Safdar SIR = Steric **inhibition** of resonance decreases lone-pair delocalization and should thereby increase basicity, but the opposite is happening here.

Comment: The lack of solvation might be a valid reason since both show SIR.  the more number of steric groups, the harder it is to solvate.[https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/8636/95133 ]

Comment: @Dylan Rodrigues: "It [SIR?[ increases basicity as well as the acidity...of the conjugate acid."

Comment: Steric inhibition of *protonation* is crucial here.